# Orders Rest API Missing Custom Option Label and Text Value

Tags: magento2, rest-api, api, custom-options, customizable-options

I'm trying to retrieve orders from the REST API in Magento Community 2.4.3
with endpoints like /rest/default/V1/orders and /rest/default/V1/orders/items
but while I can see the values for custom options of the items in the order, I can't see their labels or real values. For example:

```
    "product_option": {
    "extension_attributes": {
        "custom_options": [
            {
                "option_id": "1234",
                "option_value": "John Cena"
            },
            {
                "option_id": "1235",
                "option_value": "215"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to retrieve it as

```
{
    "option_id": "1234",
    "option_label": "What's your Name",
    "option_value": "John Cena"
},
{
    "option_id": "1235",
    "option_label": "What's your Size",
    "option_value": "215", or replace this id with "Large"
    "option_value_desc": "Large",
}
```